# Split one column in Python dataframe to multiple columns based on special character

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe. There is a single column with multiple rows of text (?). I believe each row is a either a list or a string. My data originally started out as a `.pdml` file. I then converted it into a dictionary, then flattened it.

For ease, MWE of my data and code:

Here is my PDML file: https://pastebin.com/dZX8YJRt

Here is my Python code: https://pastebin.com/83crKggG

Otherwise, here are explained snippets:

Load PDML file

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('testFile.pdml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

Convert to dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def etree_to_dict(t):
    d = {t.tag: {} if t.attrib else None}
    children = list(t)
    if children:
        dd = defaultdict(list)
        for dc in map(etree_to_dict, children):
            for k, v in dc.items():
                dd[k].append(v)
        d = {t.tag: {k:v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v for k, v in dd.items()}}
    if t.attrib:
        d[t.tag].update(('@' + k, v) for k, v in t.attrib.items())
    if t.text:
        text = t.text.strip()
        if children or t.attrib:
            if text:
              d[t.tag]['#text'] = text
        else:
            d[t.tag] = text
    return d

a = etree_to_dict(root)         # type(a) returns "dict"
packets = a["pdml"]["packet"]   # type(packets) returns "list"
```

## normalize JSON

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 1000)
df_json = pd.json_normalize(packets)  # Normalize semi-structured JSON data into a flat table
```

Here's an example of some of the text in one row of this dataframe, `df_json[:1]`.

```
df_json[:1]

[{u'field': [{'@name': 'num', '@show': '337', '@pos': '0', '@value': '151', '@size': '66', '@showname': 'Number'}, {'@name': 'len', '@show': '66', '@pos': '0', '@value': '42', '@size': '66', '@showname': 'Frame Length'}, {'@name': 'caplen', '@show': '66', '@pos': '0', '@value': '42', '@size': '66', '@showname': 'Captured Length'}, {'@name': 'timestamp', '@show': 'Mar 22, 2020 23:45:34.071253000 Pacific Daylight Time', '@pos': '0', '@value': '1584945934.071253000', '@size': '66', '@showname': 'Captured Time'}], u'@pos': u'0', u'@name': u'geninfo', u'@size': u'66', u'@showname': u'General information'}, {u'field': [{'@name': 'frame.interface_id', '@show': '0', '@pos': '0', 'field': [{'@pos': '0', '@name': 'frame.interface_name', '@size': '0', '@show': '\\Device\\NPF_{E1BDF0DA-D1E2-4F8A-A79F-16CB7121EE0B}', '@showname': 'Interface name: \\Device\\NPF_{E1BDF0DA-D1E2-4F8A-A79F-16CB7121EE0B}'}, {'@pos': '0', '@name': 'frame.interface_description', '@size': '0', '@show': 'Wi-Fi 2', '@show...
```

Here is a cleaner subset of the above for the sake of understanding:

```
<field name="num" pos="0" show="335" showname="Number" value="14f" size="66"/>
<field name="len" pos="0" show="66" showname="Frame Length" value="42" size="66"/>
<field name="caplen" pos="0" show="66" showname="Captured Length" value="42" size="66"/>
<field name="timestamp" pos="0" show="Mar 22, 2020 23:45:34.045301000 Pacific Daylight Time" showname="Captured Time" value="1584945934.045301000" size="66"/>
<field name="frame.interface_id" showname="Interface id: 0 (\Device\NPF_{E1BDF0DA-D1E2-4F8A-A79F-16CB7121EE0B})" size="0" pos="0" show="0">
<field name="frame.interface_name" showname="Interface name: \Device\NPF_{E1BDF0DA-D1E2-4F8A-A79F-16CB7121EE0B}" size="0" pos="0" show="\Device\NPF_{E1BDF0DA-D1E2-4F8A-A79F-16CB7121EE0B}"/>
<field name="frame.interface_description" showname="Interface description: Wi-Fi 2" size="0" pos="0" show="Wi-Fi 2"/>
...
```

How do I create multiple columns from this cluttered yet structured string?

The obvious thing seems to be to string splitting but I couldn't get it to work. Not sure if that is due to my inability, a limitation of the package or perhaps there's a better way. Here's what I tried:

```
df_json.proto.str.split(pat = "@", expand=True)
```

The result was:

```
    0
0   NaN
```

Ideally, I would get a table that looks roughly like:

```
num    len    timestamp                                                 ...
335    66     Mar 22, 2020 23:45:34.071253000 Pacific Daylight Time     ...
```

you'll notice that the names for the new columns are from the `@name` part of the string/list (?) and the values for the new columns are from the `@show` part. It seems like I am very far off so a full code solution is preferred.

Comment: This does not look like string data - this looks like json (?) data pulled from an API or something.   It would be a mistake to use string parsing tools on this.  Instead, consider parsing this as json (or whatever format).  Python has e.g. read_json(), although it may not work "out of the box"

Comment: @anon01 I'm not sure what the correct terminology is here. I guess I should have clarified that it looks like "each row in my dataframe is a string, formatted in a JSON structure"? I have included a parsimonious version my code in a pastebin, if that helps. But I will take your advice under advisement and explore the JSON parsing approach more thoroughly. Thanks.